# Run a customized version of a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here's our basic requirements:

- We have a base Rails application, which is being actively maintained.
- We want to offer a customized version of this app, given that:

  - servers must reside in our customer's premise and run on a different domain.
  - there's a specific logging instrumentation for their own monitoring in the datacenter.

To do that, I can see several options to achieve that goal:

- Git branch
- `Rails::Engine`
- `Rails::Application`

The most obvious answer would be Git branch, for full flexibility.

However I'm not sure if it's a good idea, because the code base is largely shared and the mainline has a lot more activities - catching up with rebase / merge could be just extra hassle.

We want to decouple the original and the customized versions as far as possible. In other words, we want to have as less often conflicts as possible between the original and the customized.

`Rails::Engine` or `Rails::Application` seemed like a close idea (I'm not familiar with Rails Engines), but I don't understand how to have `OurApp::Application` and `OurCustomizedApp::Application` in one place and switch between them globally and dynamically.

Probably it would be nice to have:

- custom initializers, controllers and views in a separate directory to override (or patch) the original
- ability to specify which app (the original or the customized) to boot by an environment variable like `RAILS_APP`
- separate config files, like so: `config/database.yml` to be `config/customer1/database.yml`
- ability to use the same `deploy.rb` for capistrano (probably with `config/servers.yml` and `config/customer1/servers.yml` to define roles and IPs?)

Is there practices / conventions for our requirements? Any advice?

Our apps run on Ruby 1.9.2 + Rails 3.0.3.

**UPDATE**

We started it as a Git branch. We created a rake task to generate a file at `config/branch` that includes text like "master" or "customized", and application.rb reads it upon bootstrap. Configs like `database.yml` or `servers.yml` now live in `config/mainline/` or `config/customized/`, and application.rb handles them accordingly.

```
config.paths.config.database = "config/#{branch}/database.yml"
```

Not perfect, but good enough for now. I'll update when we find a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's not the precise answer you're after, but I believe Git is going to be the least amount of work - and the easiest to manage, long-term - over customising the app and adding logic to handle the additional config files, modifying your deploy files and also managing the (potentially) new css/js/template files.

Using rebase & merge are going to be a lot less error-prone, and as long as you keep your branches synced on a regular basis, you shouldn't have any serious problems keeping them both up-to-date. After all, that's what Git is good at! ;)

Comment: We've ended up with Git branch and it's been working quite well so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think the best approach is to do this the old fashioned way.

First, add a singleton class to your project (in `/lib`) called something like `Affiliate`. This class should supply default implementations (whatever you want your base application to use) for any parts of the application that can be customized. At this point, your application functions the same, but has hooks to allow customization.

At your customer's site, deploy the same source code (shipped as a gem, maybe?), but also deploy a Rails plugin that overrides `Affiliate` so its singleton `instance` method returns a custom subclass that supplies customer-specific information or behaviours.

**Edited to add:** The risk with this approach is that developers inadvertantly break things because they only test their changes against the default affiliate. You should use automated testing and continuous integration to catch this.

Comment: our customization is relatively small, but large enough to not fit in a single class, and where to allow customization is unpredictable from the mainline's standpoint. Customization needs much power like custom initializers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have two interesting requirements here.  You ask how to have two separate applications and switch between them dynamically.  I am assuming that you wanting to cohost different 'versions' of the same application and have the app switch to different customizations based on the domain.  However this very different from say using Git branches to deploy two different applications.

Can you clarify your requirements here?

I would not recommend Git branches as a solution here.  I would recommend using engines. Especially bundling your engine into a gem.

Include the gem into your Custom project and then use the traditional ways of overriding functionality in an engine.  You can also use the traditional methods of extending existing Ruby code to override functionality in your gem.

This way you keep all of differences laid out in a separate project.  This separate project will also have it's own set of tests, etc.

Comment: while I think it is a good idea in general to have an Engine to cohost multiple apps, I'm not sure about maintain it as a gem - our activity on the mainline app is pretty intense, and creating a gem for each commit wouldn't be realistic. It sounds as if the web app is deployed from gem, not from git repo. I'd take it the other way around - the application for the mainline, and the engine / plugin for the customized, however it doesn't seem like a good fit either.

Answer (score 0):

We use Git to do that quite often.